# Diferença entre datas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida no *sql server*.

Baseado na tabela abaixo, como posso pegar a diferença **em dias** as quais leva para ir de uma fase para a outra do mesmo cliente, ou seja, diferença fase a fase.

[image: imagem exemplo de uma tabela]

**Exemplo:**

- A diferença entre o `id` 2 e 1 são de 9 dias;
- Entre o `id` 3 e o 2 são de 10 dias;

Comment: Deu certo a resposta para você Lucas? se sim pode aceitar como resposta da sua pergunta!?

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar a função [LEAD que acessa os dados da linha subsequente, ou seja, essa função utilizada no](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213125(v=sql.120).aspx) `SELECT` [server para comparar a linha atual com os valores da linha seguinte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213125(v=sql.120).aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, data , data_next)  AS sub
FROM (
  SELECT [data], lead([data],1,0) over (order by id) as data_next FROM test1) 
AS T
```

[Exemplo SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84160/1)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [SQL 2012 Funções LEAD e LAG](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/10272.sql-2012-funcoes-lead-e-lag.aspx)
- [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213125(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Opa! Esses `Lead` e `Lag` aí _são 'novidades'_ boas!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o [Datediff()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) você consegue pegar a diferença entra datas.

O `Select` abaixo resolve seu problema para um caso específico.

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07f3a/5)

```
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(
    day 
    , (SELECT Data FROM Teste WHERE ID =1) 
    , (SELECT Data FROM Teste WHERE ID =2)
  )  AS DiferencaEmDias
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queria deixar a **solução dinâmica** , você pode criar uma `procedure` como no exemplo abaixo, no caso ela recebe como parâmetro dois `Id`.

**Exemplo:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DiferencaFases 
    @idInicial INT
    , @idFinal INT
AS
  SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(
    day 
    , (SELECT Data FROM Teste WHERE ID =@idInicial) 
    , (SELECT Data FROM Teste WHERE ID =@idFinal)
  )  AS DiferencaEmDias
GO
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar usar subselect na cláusula `select`, você pode cruzar os dados da tabela usando um ranking por cliente.

Assim:

```
SELECT 
    SOURCE.ID,
    SOURCE.CLIENTE,
    SOURCE.FASE,
    SOURCE.DATA,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, QUERY.DATA, SOURCE.DATA) DIAS
FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTE ORDER BY FASE) AS RANKING, 
             T.ID, 
             T.CLIENTE, 
             T.FASE, 
             T.DATA FROM Teste T) SOURCE
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTE ORDER BY CLIENTE, FASE) AS RANKING, 
                       T.CLIENTE,
                       T.FASE, 
                       T.DATA FROM Teste T) QUERY ON QUERY.CLIENTE = SOURCE.CLIENTE AND (QUERY.RANKING = SOURCE.RANKING - 1)
```

A depender do cenário real onde você pretende aplicar o ganho de performance ao evitar subselect pode ser bem interessante.

Este exemplo [está disponível no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afe94/1)